# Implementing clone() in a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, clone

I have two classes: the parent class A and some subclass B, which extends A and has several more fields than A. I want to be able to clone both of these classes, so I have overridden the `clone()` method from the `Object` class.

Since class B is basically class A with some extra fields I would like to use the clone of class A in the `clone()` implementation of class B. I have tried the something along the lines of:

```
    public class A
    {
      public Object clone()
      {
        A cloneA = new A();
        cloneA.foo = this.foo;
        cloneA.bar = this.bar;
        return cloneA;
      }
    }

    public class B extends B
    {
      public Object clone()
      {
        Object cloneA = super.clone();
        B cloneB = (B)cloneA;
        cloneB.fieldSpecificForB = this.fieldSpecificForB;
        return cloneB;
      }
    }
```

This way I would not have to duplicate all the clone logic from A's `clone()` method in B's `clone()` method. Unfortanely this does not work since Java does not allow an object of class A to be casted to an object of class B. I searched around for an answer on how to do this, but it seems there is no way to reuse the cloning logic from A. Does this mean that every time I add another field to A, I have to manually add the copying of this field to the `clone()` method of *all* the subclasses. This seems to be very error-prone...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11541044/829571

Comment: possible duplicate of [Effective Java: Analysis of the clone() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540792/effective-java-analysis-of-the-clone-method)

Comment: Like @Mathias suggested the issue is that B is not extending class A. If you are not able to extend then you should do the copy.

Comment: I see I omitted some code in my original post. I changed it to convey more closely to what I tried to do in my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way `clone` works is, is that it copies *all fields* for you automatically. You must however call `super.clone()` for it to work:

```
public class A implements Cloneable  // add 'implements'
{
  public Object clone()
  {
    A cloneA = super.clone(); // this copies all fields and returns something of *the same type* as 'this'...
    return cloneA;
  }
}

public class B extends A //supposed to extend 'A' right?
{
  public Object clone()
  {
    Object cloneA = super.clone(); // this returns object of runtime type B
    B cloneB = (B)cloneA; // will work
    return cloneB;
  }
}
```

Edit: Actually your `clone` methods do nothing now, so it is equivalent to write:

```
public class A implements Cloneable  //add 'implements'
{

}

public class B extends A //supposed to extend 'A' right?
{

}
```

The `implements Cloneable` part is the one that does the trick. See also [Cloneable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I noticed I made some errors in my OP (mainly B not extending A and A.clone() not returning anything). It seems I misunderstood the way in which the Cloneable interface and super.clone() work. I'll try to implement it right this time using your example.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your implementation of `A#clone()`. You should never create the instance you will return in the `clone` method by using `new`, but always by calling `super.clone()`, exactly to avoid the error you are now experiencing.

So adjust your class A to

```
public class A
{
  @Override
  protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
  {
    A cloneA = (A)super.clone();
    cloneA.foo = this.foo;
    cloneA.bar = this.bar;
    return cloneA;
  }
}
```

Comment: If all classes up the hierarchy construct the new object by calling `super.clone()`, yours should to, but if any of them do it by calling a copy constructor, yours must do so as well.  I find irksome the notion that one should use copy constructors because `clone` is fundamentally broken, since the whole *reason* it's "broken" in the first place is the belief that copy constructors are somehow better.